# Determine whether the set of all functions on the interval $[0,1]$ that vanish at $0.5$ is a vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

My approach:

1) The set is non-empty, as it includes the zero function.

2) The set is closed under scalar multiplication:

$\mathit (\alpha f)(0.5) = \alpha f(0.5) = \alpha (0) = 0$, where $\alpha$ is an element of the real numbers.

3) The set is closed under addition:

$\mathit(f+g)(0.5) = f(0.5) + g(0.5) = 0 + 0 = 0$

Then, the set is a subspace of the vector space $C[0,1]$ and must also be a vector space.

Is this approach acceptable, or is it required that I first prove the closure properties and then verify each of the 8 vector space axioms one by one?

Comment: It is ok, being a subset of a vector space (of functions $[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ i suppose), it is enough to show (2) and (3) in the OP. In fact, the proof is shorter if we argue alternatively that the space is the kernel of the evaluation map $f\to f(0.5)$. (Well, we may argue that we have to show the linearity of the evaluation map, then this argument would be longer...)

Comment: I would say this is acceptable.  It is well-known that the set of all real-valued functions on a given domain forms a vector space, so to prove that some subset is a subspace, all you have to do is to show it's closed under addition and scalar multiplication.